# php server for Java Midlet client

Tags: php, java-me, midlet, x10

how can i set up a php server that can communicate with a client directly. i want to use it to serve java Midlets. say, get records from a DB then return them as a string...im on X10hosting but plan on shifting to a paid one that allows python cgi should php approach fail.

thanx in advance

Comment: This article should get you started: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/PHP-Interacting-with-J2ME/